# How would you be able to resize the main window depending on the screen size in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, size, screen

So, this is my code:

```
<Window x:Name="LauncherWindow" x:Class="PlayProjectBilly.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlayProjectBilly"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
   Title="Project Billy" Height= "460" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Visible" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="Game-Icon.ico" Width="640">
```

And I would really like to find out how would you be able to make the main window resize in percentage depending on the users screen size, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind Height and width to SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight & SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth respectively.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx